# Conditional Expectation Notation in ARCH Model

Tags: garch, conditional-expectation, notation

I'm new to ARCH models, and I have a question about the correct notation for expressing the conditional expectation of the return at time $t(r_t)$ given the information available up to time t-1. I'd appreciate some guidance on which of the two versions below is the correct way to write this, or if both versions are acceptable.

Given the following formulas and equations from an ARCH(1) model:

\begin{equation}
r_t = \sigma_t e_t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e_t \sim \text{white noise}(0, 1)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sigma_t = \sqrt{\omega + \alpha_1 r_{t-1}^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E(r_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots) = E(\sigma_t e_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= \sigma_t E(e_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= \sigma_t \times 0 = 0
\end{equation}

Version 1:
\begin{align*}
E(r_t) &= E_{r_{t-1}} E_{r_{t-2}} \cdots \left[ E(r_t | r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots) \right] \\
&= E_{r_{t-1}} E_{r_{t-2}} \cdots E[0] \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Version 2:
\begin{align*}
E(r_t) &= E[E(r_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots)] \\
&= E[0] \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Can someone please point out which of the two versions is the correct one, or if both versions are correct?

Comment: Version 2 is correct.  In version 1, the notations such as "$E_{r_{t - 1}}$" are unclear.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you for the response.
Regarding the equation $$E(r_t) = E[E(r_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, \ldots)] = E[0] = 0$$ I understand that the outer expectation operator is applying the law of iterated expectations. However, I've never seen it conditioning on more than one variable before. Is the outer expectation operator essentially integrating over$r_{t-1}$, $r_t$, and so on?

Comment: \begin{align*}
\sum_{y \in \Omega_Y} E [g(X) | Y = y] p_Y (y) &= \sum_{y \in \Omega_Y} \left( \sum_{x \in \Omega_X} g(x) p_{X|Y} (x | y) \right) p_Y (y) \
&= \sum_{x \in \Omega_X} \sum_{y \in \Omega_Y} g(x) p_{X|Y} (x | y) p_Y (y) \
&= \sum_{x \in \Omega_X} g(x) \sum_{y \in \Omega_Y} p_{X,Y} (x, y) \
&= \sum_{x \in \Omega_X} g(x) p_X (x) \
&= E [g(X)]
\end{align*}

Can the equation E(r_t) = E[E(r_t|r_{t-1}, r_{t-2}, …)] be written in a similar mathematical form, extending the concept of conditioning on a single variable to multiple variables?

Comment: The general "law of iterated expectations" is $E[X] = E[E[X|\mathscr{G}]]$, where $\mathscr{G}$ can be any sub-$\sigma$-field, which encompasses cases of one variable, multiple variables or even uncountably many variables.  Of course, to fully understand this most general version, you would need some measure-theoretic probability knowledge.